# Displaying 5 strings from an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, loops, textbox

I want to display strings in a file that begins with the letter "F" **(var target = "F";)** and then print it in **footlockerExistingBlogTextBox** however only display 5 strings/lines. The file that holds the array contains more that 5 strings that begin with "F" and so I only want to display the last 5 latest entries. Thanks for your help in advance. Much appreciated.

**Below displays my code:**

```
var target = "F";
var results = footlockerArray.Where(r => r.StartsWith(target)).Reverse();

foreach (string result in results)
{
    footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text += result;
}

for (int i = footlockerArray.Length - 1; i > footlockerArray.Length - 5; i--)
{
    footlockerArray.Reverse();
    footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text += footlockerArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse and use Take(5):

```
     footlockerArray
        .Where(o => o.StartsWith("F"))
        .Reverse()
        .Take(5)
        .Reverse()
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(o => footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text += o);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you can get the results like:

```
var results = footlockerArray.Where(r => r.StartsWith(target))
                             .OrderByDescending(r=> r)
                             .Take(5);
```

Then to get a string separated by a new line you can use `string.Join` like:

```
footlockerExistingBlogTextBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results);
```

Comment: You should order by descending before you take 5.  Otherwise you are taking the top 5 and reversing them.

Comment: Additionally, you're still ordered wrong. They should be reversed again later on. Now you're taking the last 5 but they are still in reverse order. I'm not sure ordering them is correct because the OP never said they were in order - just that the last 5 are requested.

Comment: @Paul, yes now I see the OP has tried Reverse twice, If op needs an ascending order then another `OrderBy(r=> r)` could be add in the end of statement. I will leave that for OP.